# I am an employee but design is not in my contract, I have left the company and they still use my designs. Do I have any rights to the work?

Tags: copyright, contract

I was an IT engineer but did design for them as they found out it was a hobby of mine, I have done many corporate designs for them and they still use them to this day, do I have any rights to the images as it was not in my contract to do this, I Just did it as it was expected of me once they learned I could. I was a trainee IT engineer but was being hired out to do websites and company logos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [The Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

As an "employee" everything you create is owned by the company you work for, entirely.

Employees are considered to be in a [work-for-hire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire) position and retain no rights to anything, regardless of their job description.

**IF** there is some sort of contract, which is not customary in the United States, you should consult the contract. It will have a section dictating who owns what in relation to work done by employees and what and employee can do with the work; for example, if it can be used in a portfolio.